# Mcrypt not decrypting

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I'm working on a small program that has to encrypt a basic sentence and echo the result. Then I want to be able to copy paste the result and be able to decode the text in the same way I encoded it. It doesn't need to be too safe, so therefore I opted to use Mcrypt.

When I try to decrypt, it gives weird (ASCII?) letters and I don't understand where they come from. Tried to solve it with a base64 encode/decode, but that didn't help either. What do I need to change to get it to work properly?

```
<?php

// Define Mcrypt variables
$enc = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;
$mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
$key = 'SanderDitIsNodigVoor16bi';
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size($enc, $mode), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);

// Check if 'submit' is set
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // Check if 'text' is set
    if (!empty($_POST['text'])) {

        // Check if 'crypt' is set
        if (isset($_POST['crypt'])) {

            // Retrieve 'text'
            $input = $_POST['text'];

            // Check for encrypt/decrypt
            switch ($_POST['crypt']) {
                case 'encrypt':
                    $result = encrypt();
                    break;
                case 'decrypt':
                    $result = decrypt();
                    break;
            }

            echo $result;
        }

        // If 'crypt' is not set
        else {
            echo 'Please select encrypt or decrypt.';
        }
    }

    // If 'text' is not set
    else {
        echo 'Please fill in some text.';
    }
}

function encrypt() {
    global $enc, $key, $input, $mode, $iv;
    $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt($enc, $key, $input, $mode, $iv);
    $output = base64_encode($encrypted);
    return $output;
}

function decrypt() {
    global $enc, $key, $input, $mode, $iv;
    $decrypted = base64_decode($input);
    $output = mcrypt_decrypt($enc, $key, $decrypted, $mode, $iv);
    return $output;
}

?>
```

To be clear, if I include the mcrypt_decrypt in the encryption to make sure it's not something I messed up in the function itself, it does decrypt it properly. But when I try to separate the two, it doesn't. I'm stumped.

Comment: You may be misunderstanding the purpose of encrypting. If it doesn't need to be secure then why encrypt to begin with?

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: It's just an exercise to wrap my head around the concept of encryption. I've dived into OpenSLL encryption, but I'm running an older version of PHP, so that isn't working for me.

Comment: such awful code

Answer (score 1):

you are sending to both `encrypt` and `decrypt` the same input , which is :

```
$input = $_POST['text'];
```

encrypt will encrypt successfully , but you are always trying to decrypt 'decrypted' phrase !

you must pass the `encrypted` phrase to decrypt function

and don't forget about the important note that [mcrypt_*](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php) extension has been deprecated :

> This extension rely in libmcrypt which is dead, unmaintained since
>   2007.
>
> Please don't rely on it, consider switching to well maintained
>   alternatives (openssl, crypt, password hashing functions, phpseclib,
>   password_compat...)

and , try to stop using `global` variables , it isn't recommended .

Comment: @Sander Yes: "stop using global variables"

Comment: Since the code only calls upon each function depending on what button is set (for completeness I should've added the HTML form as well), doesn't that mean it doesn't matter that the text input is the same for both? You'd select 'Decrypt' and put in a decrypted text to decrypt it and vice versa.

Comment: well, check out , https://3v4l.org/kP9pM , and for test-mental purposes , echo the `$input` inside each function to check the passed value .